# React fragment in decorator

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I need to make next page dynamically to not repeat myself, but don't exactly understand how I can make a React fragment for returning a function in this way.

```
export const DesignSystemPage = (component: FC) => {

    const componentInstance = ?? // it should be component instance
    
    const DSPage: NextPageWithLayout = () => {
        return {componentInstance}
    }

    DSPage.getLayout = function getLayout(page: React.ReactElement) {
        return (
          <Providers 
          themeProps={DSPage.theme}
          designSystemProps={DSPage.designSystem}
          >
            <DesignSystemLayout title='Design system | Summary'>
              {page}
            </DesignSystemLayout>
          </Providers>
        )
    } 
    DSPage.theme = {
        themes: ['daisy', 'cmyk'],
    } 
    DSPage.designSystem = {
        pages: [
          'summary', 
          'color-schema', 
          'typography',
          'buttons'
        ]
    }
    return DSPage
}
export default DesignSystemPage
```

I tried to play around React Fragment constructor or {} brakets, but with no luck.